# How do I use the IPU Model with the Graphcore Docker containers?

Tags: docker, ipu

I’ve had a look at the Graphcore documentation and it mentions the “IPU Model” that I can use without access to actual IPU hardware.  So, I downloaded the Graphcore provided Docker images and there is a long list of options:

```
graphcore/tools       1.2.0                     21951ab865eb       7 weeks ago        271MB 
graphcore/tools       1.2.0-bionic-20200112     21951ab865eb       7 weeks ago        271MB 
graphcore/tools       latest                    21951ab865eb       7 weeks ago        271MB 
graphcore/tensorflow  1                         6a50c5b868bc       7 weeks ago        1.84GB 
graphcore/tensorflow  1.2.0-1                   6a50c5b868bc       7 weeks ago        1.84GB 
graphcore/tensorflow  1.2.0-1-bionic-20200112   6a50c5b868bc       7 weeks ago        1.84GB 
graphcore/tensorflow  latest                    6a50c5b868bc       7 weeks ago        1.84GB 
graphcore/tensorflow  1.2.0-2                   daae2de8acd8       7 weeks ago        1.93GB 
graphcore/tensorflow  1.2.0-2-bionic-20200112   daae2de8acd8       7 weeks ago        1.93GB 
graphcore/tensorflow  2                         daae2de8acd8       7 weeks ago        1.93GB 
graphcore/poplar      1.2.0                     bfe711b31eb6       7 weeks ago        710MB 
graphcore/poplar      1.2.0-bionic-20200112     bfe711b31eb6       7 weeks ago        710MB 
graphcore/poplar      latest
```

However, none of them mention the IPU Model. Does this mean I can’t use the IPU Model with the Docker containers? Is this something that Graphcore will be supporting in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Support for the IPU Model is built in at the Poplar level and exposed in each framework, hence why there is no specific IPU Model Docker image.

You can choose whichever Docker image corresponds to the framework you want to use on the IPU; for example, choose the `graphcore/tensorflow:1` image if you would like to use TensorFlow 1. Once you’ve chosen the framework, the method of selecting a real device vs an IPU model is framework specific. For TensorFlow, you can set an environment variable [as described here](https://docs.graphcore.ai/projects/tensorflow-user-guide/en/latest/device_selection.html#tf-poplar-flags-environment-variable).

The IPU Model can be used to test if your machine learning models will compile and fit on a physical IPU. See [here](https://docs.graphcore.ai/projects/poplar-user-guide/en/latest/poplar_programs.html#programming-with-poplar) for more information and details about some caveats.